# Symfony-2.0 vendors Apache

Tags: php, apache, symfony

I've installed symfony vendors & when I'm trying to get page Apache service restarts with message "...Memory can't be read".

When i'm opening basic test page with just phpinfo() there everything is ok. 
And when i've started my first steps from manual (before vendors installation) everything gone ok.

My current config: WinXP SP3, Apache2.2, PHP5.3.10, Symfony2.0.11, Postgres9.1, Git Bash, deps installed without errors(not from first 10 times but as a result, list is below), initial symfony check paseed (all "OK"), in php.ini memory_limit = 512M... i dunno what else can be useful...

I'l appreciate any advice about my problem.

content of deps file:

```
[symfony]
    git=git://github.com/symfony/symfony.git
    version=v2.0.12

[twig]
    git=http://github.com/fabpot/Twig.git
    version=v1.6.2

[monolog]
    git=http://github.com/Seldaek/monolog.git
    version=1.0.2

[doctrine-common]
    git=git://github.com/doctrine/common.git
    version=2.1.4

[doctrine-dbal]
    git=git://github.com/doctrine/dbal.git
    version=2.1.6

[doctrine]
    git=git://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2.git
    version=2.1.6

[swiftmailer]
    git=git://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer.git
    version=v4.1.5

[assetic]
    git=git://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic.git
    version=v1.0.3

[twig-extensions]
    git=http://github.com/fabpot/Twig-extensions.git

[metadata]
    git=http://github.com/schmittjoh/metadata.git
    version=1.0.0

[SensioFrameworkExtraBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sensio/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/FrameworkExtraBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[JMSSecurityExtraBundle]
    git=git://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSecurityExtraBundle.git
    target=/bundles/JMS/SecurityExtraBundle
    version=origin/1.0.x

[SensioDistributionBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sensio/SensioDistributionBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/DistributionBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[SensioGeneratorBundle]
    git=http://github.com/sensio/SensioGeneratorBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Sensio/Bundle/GeneratorBundle
    version=origin/2.0

[AsseticBundle]
    git=http://github.com/symfony/AsseticBundle.git
    target=/bundles/Symfony/Bundle/AsseticBundle
    version=v1.0.1
```

a small part of apache error log:

```
[Tue Mar 20 17:50:00 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.19 (Win32) PHP/5.3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 20 17:50:00 2012] [notice] Server built: May 20 2011 17:39:35
[Tue Mar 20 17:50:00 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 12844
[Tue Mar 20 17:50:00 2012] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(477): Parent: Sent the scoreboard to the child
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.56 for ServerName
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.56 for ServerName
[Tue Mar 20 17:50:00 2012] [notice] Child 12844: Child process is running
[Tue Mar 20 17:50:00 2012] [info] Parent: Duplicating socket 208 and sending it to child process 12844
[Tue Mar 20 17:50:00 2012] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(398): Child 12844: Retrieved our scoreboard from the parent.
[Tue Mar 20 17:50:00 2012] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(595): Parent: Sent 1 listeners to child 12844
[Tue Mar 20 17:50:00 2012] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(554): Child 12844: retrieved 1 listeners from parent
[Tue Mar 20 17:50:00 2012] [notice] Child 12844: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue Mar 20 17:50:00 2012] [notice] Child 12844: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Mar 20 17:50:00 2012] [notice] Child 12844: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Tue Mar 20 17:53:00 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.56 for ServerName
[Tue Mar 20 17:53:00 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.19 (Win32) PHP/5.3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Mar 20 17:53:00 2012] [notice] Server built: May 20 2011 17:39:35
[Tue Mar 20 17:53:00 2012] [notice] Parent: Created child process 14024
[Tue Mar 20 17:53:00 2012] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(477): Parent: Sent the scoreboard to the child
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.56 for ServerName
httpd.exe: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.56 for ServerName
[Tue Mar 20 17:53:00 2012] [notice] Child 14024: Child process is running
[Tue Mar 20 17:53:00 2012] [info] Parent: Duplicating socket 208 and sending it to child process 14024
[Tue Mar 20 17:53:00 2012] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(398): Child 14024: Retrieved our scoreboard from the parent.
[Tue Mar 20 17:53:00 2012] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(595): Parent: Sent 1 listeners to child 14024
[Tue Mar 20 17:53:00 2012] [debug] mpm_winnt.c(554): Child 14024: retrieved 1 listeners from parent
[Tue Mar 20 17:53:00 2012] [notice] Child 14024: Acquired the start mutex.
[Tue Mar 20 17:53:00 2012] [notice] Child 14024: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Tue Mar 20 17:53:00 2012] [notice] Child 14024: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Comment: Any more detail in Apache error logs?

Comment: nope. i even added "LogLevel debug" to httpd.conf - all is clear, no error messages, just a command like restart

Comment: Maybe something in Windows sys logs?

Comment: in application log only an error about specifying domain name

Comment: in sys log only poupup with error: Всплывающее окно приложения: httpd.exe - Ошибка приложения : Инструкция по адресу "0x00813b02" обратилась к памяти по адресу "0x055f1000". Память не может быть "read".

"ОК" -- завершение приложения
"Отмена" -- отладка приложения

Comment: it says: instruction from address "0x00813b02" requested memory address "0x055f1000". Memory can't be "read". Press "Ok" to exit or "Cancel" to debug

Comment: Sounds like this is an OS-level issue - I don't recall that one from my time using Apache+PHP on Windows however. I'd suggest ensuring you have the latest Apache (everything else looks latest!) to start with. Also, if you are able to, install Vista or Win7 in a VM to see if you get the problem there. Lastly I'd try installing on a different machine, to see if you have a install-specific/hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved it! My recipe is: downloading php5.4 (zip pack) & copying files with owerwrite to php folder. Only one minus: couldn't find php_apc.dll for current php version  :(

Thanks **halfer** for responds!