# Is it posible to use symfony 2.0 with WAMP server reliably?

Tags: php, apache, symfony, wamp, wampserver

This is my setup:

- Windows XP SP2
- WAMP 2.2 (php 5.3.9, apache 2.2.21, mysql 5.5.20)
- Symfony 2.0

I run into a problem which is basically this:

[Symfony-2.0 vendors Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788980/symfony-2-0-vendors-apache)

Everything seems to be fine:

- Running mysqltest.php connects OK to the database.
- localhost/web/config.php is OK (just recommends setting up intl and APC)
- "php app/bin doctrine:schema:create" creates the schema successfully.

But, when I try to:

- "localhost/web/app.php"
- "localhost/web/app_dev.php"

Apache crashes (windows popup saying something about php5ts.dll) and the only meaningful thing on the log says:

- [Fri Apr 27 05:03:54 2012] [notice] Child 3528: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
- [Fri Apr 27 05:07:00 2012] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 3221225477 -- Restarting.
- [Fri Apr 27 05:07:01 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.21 (Win32) PHP/5.3.9 configured -- resuming normal operations

The solution to the question I referenced previously is to use php 5.4, well, as stated in
[How do I get PDO to work on WAMP with PHP 5.4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10155624/how-do-i-get-pdo-to-work-on-wamp-with-php-5-4) 
besides 5.4 not being officially supported by WAMP, many extensions don't work on 5.4 (APC, PDO maybe?).

Older versions of php are also ruled out. Official WAMP addons exist only for php 5.3.0 and 5.3.1, while symfony2 requires at least 5.3.2.

I also tried this on a Windows Server 2003 machine, with the same results.
This is taking so much time I'm even considering throwing in a Linux VM on the server with my usual symfony setup.

So I need to know whether it's posible to have a stable symfony2/WAMP2.2 environment which does not imply losing extensions and symfony2 functionality such as doctrine.

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Tried disabling php5ts.dll in php.ini?

Comment: Not really, I didn't know that was posible, now that I looked it up, it's a thread safe php dll. Sounds good, but I don't have the environment setup anymore, I may try it some other time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not manage to make wampserver work.

I have also tried [XAMPP 1.7.7 (php 5.3.8)](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) and [other distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_WAMPs) as well and ran into the same issue over and over.

Apparently the error message I have been receiveing is not useful at all, as suggested [here](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38086), it's just a "something crashed" message.

I couldn't find any other message out of the logs in any of the installations, so I can't tell wether this is a symfony2 bug, a php bug or an apache bug.

Anyway, the error message I got being completely useless, all I could do is moving away from Windows. I setup a LAMP(Linux) environment in virtual machine and run it from a Windos host, it's been some months and I haven't had any issues so far.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following lines at the end of my 'httpd.conf' file of the running Apache server based on the explanation given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34452918/1374947):

```
<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadStackSize 8888888
</IfModule>
```

And so far didn't get any issues.